# C# Duda sobre asignar contraseña para Workbook de Excel

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-office, contraseña

Ultimamente he habia estado investigando sore la forrma de asignarle contraseñas a un Libro o archivo de excel por medio de C#, pero cuando ejecuto mi proceso, la funcion correspondiente ( Protect() ) que me deberia asignar la contraseña no se la asigna al archivo

```
public void ProtectSheet(string Password)
        {
            wb.Protect(Password);
        }
```

¿Estare implementando algo incorrecto o hay algun error en lo que hice? Agradezco sus ayudas, adjunto codigo del proceso:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Excel
    {

        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;

        public Excel(string path)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);

        }

        public void ProtectSheet()
        {
            wb.Protect();
        }

        public void ProtectSheet(string Password)
        {
            wb.Protect(Password);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            wb.Save();
        }

        public void SaveAs(string path)
        {
            wb.SaveAs(path);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            wb.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel ex = new Excel(@"NUEVOEXCEL2");

            ex.ProtectSheet("nuevopass");
            ex.Save();
            ex.Close();

        }
    }
}
```